# Recognising template typename in runtime

Tags: c++, templates

I am in need for your expert help with this little code bellow:

```
    template<typename T> void print_element(T t)
{
    int width;
    if(pre_def_const+2 < 8) width=8;
    else width = pre_def_const+2;

    cout << left << setw(width) << setfill(' ') << t;
}
```

This function will receive only doubles and string parameters and I want to be able to diferentiate between each case.

In short I want to add something like this to that code above:

```
if(T==double) ...
if(T==string) ...
```

I need this to test for doubles being smaller than zero.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This function will receive only doubles and string parameters

Then it should not be a template. Instead create two **overloaded** functions:

```
void print_element(double d);
void print_element(std::string const& s);
```

---

Technically, there *is* a language construct which comes very close to your desired syntax: `typeid`. It's not a good solution here at all, so I'll post an example just for the sake of completeness, not because I recommend you do it like this in your real code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int pre_def_const = 10;
int left = 20;

template<typename T> void print_element(T t)
{
    if (typeid(t) == typeid(double))
    {
        std::cout << "double instantiation of template called\n";
    }

    int width;
    if(pre_def_const+2 < 8) width=8;
    else width = pre_def_const+2;

    std::cout << left << std::setw(width) << std::setfill(' ') << t;
}

int main()
{
    print_element(1.0);
    std::cout << "\n";
    print_element("x");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Christian Hackl!
Actually the function might receive 'int' as well, but the main reason I dont want to overload is because I am curious and maybe I will use it in the future...

Comment: Would you mind explaining why `typeid` shouldnt be used this way?

Comment: @ivbc: I would not use it here because the type is already known by the time `typeid` comes into play. Consider, for a moment, that you are really dealing with two different functions `void print_element<double>(double t)` and `void print_element<std::string>(std::string t)`, because that's what your template effectively becomes. In the first function, you ask if a `double` is a `double`, in the second you ask if a `std::string` is `double`. That's redundant, like asking if 1 is 1. `typeid` is usually used when you do *not* know the type at compile time, i.e. with OOP classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

```
if(std::is_same<T,double>::value){/*do somemthing*/}
if(std::is_same<T,std::string>::value){/*do somemthing*/}
```

Be sure to include `#include <type_traits>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `typeid` opearator, or by overloading the method.

Comment: "overloading" is not a keyword... :)

Comment: Well, to each their own, I guess, but this is surely a non-standard use of SO code tags.

Comment: I used to not mark them, but noticed that some posts here on SO got edited this way by other members. so.. dunno really.

Comment: I've never seen someone making such an edit. It's rather the other way round; it would not have surprised me if someone *removed* the code tags from your answer...

Comment: Well I saw an edit like that earlier this morning, under the c++ tag. Anyhow, removed it ;)